# Scraping using beautiful soup not working fully?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape some data using BeautifulSoup on python from the site 'https://www.geappliances.com/ge-appliances/kitchen/ranges/' which has some products.

```
import unittest, time, random
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

links = []
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\drivers\\geckodriver\\win64\\v0.29.1\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.geappliances.com/ge-appliances/kitchen/ranges/")
content = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

for main in soup.findAll('li', attrs = {'class' : 'product'}):    
    name=main.find('a', href=True)
    if (name != ''):
        links.append((name.get('href')).strip())
   
print("Got links : ", len(links))
exit()
```

Here in output I get:-
Got links: 0

I printed the soup and saw that this part was not there in the soup. I have been trying to get around this problem to no avail.
Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestion are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Study the source of the webpage.Check your `findAll` function.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait till the page loads. Use `time.sleep()` to pause execution for a while.

You can try like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://www.geappliances.com/ge-appliances/kitchen/ranges/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
u = soup.find('ul', class_='productGrid')
for item in u.find_all('li', class_='product'):
    print(item.find('a')['href'])

driver.close()
```

```
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Front-Control-Induction-Fingerprint-Resistant-Range-with-In-Oven-Camera-PHS93XYPFS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Electric-Pizza-Oven-PS96PZRSS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Front-Control-Gas-Double-Oven-Convection-Fingerprint-Resistant-Range-PGS960YPFS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Dual-Fuel-Slide-In-Front-Control-Fingerprint-Resistant-Range-P2S930YPFS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Electric-Double-Oven-Convection-Fingerprint-Resistant-Range-PS960YPFS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Front-Control-Induction-and-Convection-Range-with-No-Preheat-Air-Fry-PHS930BPTS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Fingerprint-Resistant-Front-Control-Induction-and-Convection-Range-with-No-Preheat-Air-Fry-PHS930YPFS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Front-Control-Gas-Range-with-No-Preheat-Air-Fry-PGS930BPTS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Front-Control-Gas-Fingerprint-Resistant-Range-with-No-Preheat-Air-Fry-PGS930YPFS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Electric-Convection-Range-with-No-Preheat-Air-Fry-PSS93BPTS
/appliance/GE-Profile-30-Smart-Slide-In-Electric-Convection-Fingerprint-Resistant-Range-with-No-Preheat-Air-Fry-PSS93YPFS
/appliance/GE-30-Slide-In-Front-Control-Gas-Double-Oven-Range-JGSS86SPSS
```